# 2D Physics Engine

Tags: c#, .net, physics-engine

Is there any physics engine for .net platform instead of the **physics2d.net** that's out now on Google code? I don't need something for XNA framework and exactly I need a library for using it straight in my C# application.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/box2dx/  - C# wrapper around the popular box2d physics engine.

Comment: Thanks but it's just a demo app. I don't know how should I use it in my own.

Comment: You should be able to read through the source code of the demo(s) to see how you should use the library in your own projects.

Comment: Box2d tutorials can be found everywhere: http://www.kerp.net/box2d/